# Permutations with Kronecker delta

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let $z,n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $1\leq z< n$. Let $\mathfrak{S}_n,\mathfrak{S}_z$ be the symmetric groups and $\delta_{i,j}$ be the Kronecker delta and $(f_n),(g_n)$ are families of functions. Then I don't understand the following line:
$$\sum\limits_{\pi,\sigma\in \mathfrak{S}_n}\prod\limits_{1\leq k \leq z}f_{\pi(k)}(x)g_{\sigma(k)}(x)
\prod\limits_{z<j \leq n}\delta_{\pi(j),\sigma(j)}\\=
\sum\limits_{\substack{A\subset [n]\\|A|=z}}\sum\limits_{\pi,\sigma\in \mathfrak{S}_z}\prod\limits_{1\leq k \leq z}f_{\pi(k)}(x)g_{\sigma(k)}(x)
|\mathfrak{S}([n]\setminus A)|$$
I understand that we only have to look at the permutations $\{1,\dots,z\}$ in the cases when $\pi(j)=\sigma(j)$ which I assume is $(n-z)$ times. I also understand that we sum over all sets of size $z$, but I am not seeing the rest. Why do we multiply with $|\mathfrak{S}([n]\setminus A)|$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that this identity is valid in general. It seems to be correct for families of functions $(f_n)_{1\leq j\leq n}$, $(g_n)_{1\leq j\leq n}$ with certain restrictions. In order to better understand what's going on we make some transformations and interpret the result.

> We have for $1\leq z\leq n$:
> \begin{align*}
> &\sum\limits_{\pi,\sigma\in \mathfrak{S}_n}\prod\limits_{1\leq k \leq z}\left(f_{\pi(k)}(x)g_{\sigma(k)}(x)\right)
> \prod\limits_{z<j \leq n}\delta_{\pi(j),\sigma(j)}\\
> &\qquad=
> \sum\limits_{\substack{A\subset [n]\\|A|=z}}\sum\limits_{\pi,\sigma\in \mathfrak{S}_z}
> \prod\limits_{1\leq k \leq z}\left(f_{\pi(k)}(x)g_{\sigma(k)}(x)\right)|\mathfrak{S}([n]\setminus A)|\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

**Left-hand side:** We can write the left-hand side of (1) as
\begin{align*}
&\sum\limits_{\pi,\sigma\in \mathfrak{S}_n}\prod\limits_{1\leq k \leq z}\left(f_{\pi(k)}(x)g_{\sigma(k)}(x)\right)
\prod\limits_{z<j \leq n}\delta_{\pi(j),\sigma(j)}\\
&\qquad=\sum_{(\pi,\sigma)\in\mathfrak{S}_{n}^2}
\prod_{k=1}^z f_{\pi(k)}(x)\prod_{k=1}^z g_{\sigma(k)}(x)\prod\limits_{j=z+1}^n\delta_{\pi(j),\sigma(j)}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

The right-hand side of (2) is just a slightly different representation. What do we sum up? We select all pairs $(\pi,\sigma)$ of permutations from $\mathfrak{S}_n^2$.

- The product
  \begin{align*}
  \prod\limits_{j=z+1}^n\delta_{\pi(j),\sigma(j)}
  =\begin{cases}
  1\qquad(\pi(z+1),\ldots,\pi(n))=(\sigma(z+1),\ldots,\sigma(n))\\
  0\qquad(\pi(z+1),\ldots,\pi(n))\ne (\sigma(z+1),\ldots,\sigma(n))\\
  \end{cases}
  \end{align*}
  is $1$ if and only if the $n-z$ right-most positions of the permutations $\pi$ and $\sigma$ coincide and $0$ otherwise. A contribution of $1$ is given in $(n-z)!$ different ways.
- The first $z$ positions of the permutations of $\pi$ and $\sigma$ can be taken arbitrarily in $\binom{n}{z}(z!)^2$ different ways, and we multiply the corresponding functions
  \begin{align*}
  \prod_{k=1}^z f_{\pi(k)}(x)\prod_{k=1}^z g_{\sigma(k)}(x)\tag{3}
  \end{align*}

**Right-hand side:** We can write the right-hand side of (1) as
\begin{align*}
&\sum\limits_{\substack{A\subset [n]\\|A|=z}}\sum\limits_{\pi,\sigma\in \mathfrak{S}_z}
\prod\limits_{1\leq k \leq z}\left(f_{\pi(k)}(x)g_{\sigma(k)}(x)\right)|\mathcal{S}([n]\setminus A)|\tag{4}\\
&\qquad=\sum\limits_{\pi,\sigma\in \mathfrak{S}_z}
\prod\limits_{1\leq k \leq z}\left(f_{\pi(k)}(x)g_{\sigma(k)}(x)\right)
\sum\limits_{\substack{A\subset [n]\\|A|=z}}(n-z)!\tag{5}\\
&\qquad=\sum\limits_{\pi,\sigma\in \mathfrak{S}_z}
\prod\limits_{1\leq k \leq z}\left(f_{\pi(k)}(x)g_{\sigma(k)}(x)\right)\binom{n}{z}(n-z)!\tag{6}\\
\end{align*}

We can considerably simplify the right-hand side of (1) written again as (4).

- The left-most sum of (4) sums over all subsets from $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ which have size $z$. Since the inner sum and products do not depend on $A$ we can factor out them putting the sum $\sum\limits_{\substack{A\subset [n]\\|A|=z}}$ to the right end of (5). Since $|\mathfrak{S}([n]\setminus A)|$ counts all permutations of elements from $[n]\setminus A$ and $|A|=z$ we have $|\mathfrak{S}([n]\setminus A)|=(n-z)!$.
- In (6) we observe there are $\binom{n}{z}$ different subsets of $[n]$ with size $z$.

**Conclusion:**

- The right-hand side of (1) in the form (6) shows that only permutations of $\mathfrak{S}_z$ are taken when building the products from (3). This is different to the left-hand side which takes elements from $[n]$ since $\pi,\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_n$.

  In other words: If $z<n$ then $f_n(x), g_n(x)$ are factors in some terms of the left-hand side of (1) but not of the right-hand side.
- It seems when looking at (1) there was some kind of misleading idea. Namely, taking for the right-hand side a *representative* from $\mathfrak{S}_z$ and use a proper multiplication. As we can see, this is not sufficient in general.
- The identity (1) is valid if for instance $n=q z$ is a multiple of $z$, $\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}\subset \{f_1,\ldots,f_z\}$, $\{g_1,\ldots,g_n\}\subset\{g_1,\ldots,g_z\}$ and when partitioning $\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}$ in equal functions, each partition has size $q$ and the same with $g_j, 1\leq j\leq n$.

**Example: $n=3,z=2$** We look at a small example and sum up left-hand side and right-hand side of (1) in detail. At first we determine the permutations which contribute to the sums. We use cycle notation
\begin{align*}
\mathfrak{S}_2&=\{\mathrm{id},(12)\}\\
\mathfrak{S}_3&=\{\mathrm{id},(12),(13),(23),(123),(132)\}
\end{align*}
and obtain
\begin{align*}
&\{(\pi,\sigma)\in\mathfrak{S}_2^2\}
=\{(\mathrm{id},\mathrm{id}),(\mathrm{id},(12)),((12),\mathrm{id}),((12),(12))\}\tag{7}\\
\\
&\{(\pi,\sigma)\in\mathfrak{S}_3^2\big|\pi(3)=\sigma(3)\}\\
&\qquad=\{(\mathrm{id},\mathrm{id}), (\mathrm{id},(12)), ((12),\mathrm{id}),\\
&\qquad\qquad ((12),(12)),((13),(13)), ((13),(123)), \\
&\qquad\qquad ((23),(23)),((23),(132)), ((123),(13)),\\
&\qquad\qquad ((123),(123)),((132),(23)),((132),(132))\}\tag{8}
\end{align*}

**Left-hand side of (1)** with $n=3, z=2$: We obtain using (8) and omitting the argument $x$ for a more compact notation:
\begin{align*}
&\color{blue}{\sum\limits_{\pi,\sigma\in \mathfrak{S}_3}\prod\limits_{1\leq k \leq 2}\left(f_{\pi(k)}g_{\sigma(k)}\right)
\prod\limits_{2<j \leq 3}\delta_{\pi(j),\sigma(j)}}\\
&=\sum\limits_{\pi,\sigma\in \mathfrak{S}_3}f_{\pi(1)}g_{\sigma(1)}f_{\pi(2)}g_{\sigma(2)}\delta_{\pi(3),\sigma(3)}\\
&=\sum\limits_{\pi,\sigma\in \mathfrak{S}_3}f_{\pi(1)}f_{\pi(2)}g_{\sigma(1)}g_{\sigma(2)}\delta_{\pi(3),\sigma(3)}\\
&=f_1f_2g_1g_2+f_1f_2g_2g_1+f_2f_1g_1g_2+f_2f_1g_2g_1\\
&\qquad+f_3f_2g_3g_2+f_3f_2g_2g_3+f_1f_3g_1g_3+f_1f_3g_3g_1\\
&\qquad+f_2f_3g_3g_2+f_2f_3g_2g_3+f_3f_1g_1g_3+f_3f_1g_3g_1\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=4\left(f_1f_2g_1g_2+f_1f_3g_1g_3+f_2f_3g_2g_3\right)}
\end{align*}

**Right-hand side of (1)** with $n=3, z=2$: We obtain using (7) and again omitting the argument $x$:
\begin{align*}
&\color{blue}{\sum\limits_{\substack{A\subset [3]\\|A|=2}}\sum\limits_{\pi,\sigma\in \mathfrak{S}_2}
\prod\limits_{1\leq k \leq 2}\left(f_{\pi(k)}g_{\sigma(k)}\right)|\mathfrak{S}([3]\setminus A)|}\\
&\qquad =\binom{3}{2}\sum\limits_{\pi,\sigma\in \mathcal{S}_2}
f_{\pi(1)}f_{\pi(2)}g_{\sigma(1)}g_{\sigma(2)}\cdot 1!\\
&\qquad=3\left(f_1f_2g_1g_2+f_1f_2g_2g_1+f_2f_1g_1g_2+f_2f_1g_2g_1\right)\\
&\qquad\color{blue}{=12 f_1f_2g_1g_2}
\end{align*}
clearly showing the difference between left-hand side and right-hand side of (1).

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation. Now this is much clearer what is going on. Thank you.

Comment: @Matriz: You're welcome! :-)